# Representing a 64 bit integer in GNU/Linux

Tags: c++, c, 64-bit, long-integer

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 (64 bit) with `gcc` and I wanted to use a 64 bit integer in my C++ program.

On my system the outputs of `sizeof(long)`,  `sizeof(long long int)` and `sizeof(int64_t)` are all 8 bytes (64 bits).

Which qualifier (`long`, `long long`, or `int64_t`) would you recommend for using 64 bit integers?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`int64_t` -- This is because it is the most portable representation. The other two could be represented differently on other machines.

Comment: +1. Consider Win64 LLP64 and Unix LP64: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#64-bit_data_models

Answer (score 9):

**int64_t.** If you need 64 bits, declare it explicitly. The size of long and long long varies by machine.

Answer (score 8):

Do you need exactly 64 bits or at least 64 bits?

Use whichever of `int64_t`, `int_least64_t`, or `int_fast64_t` most clearly expresses your intent.  (All three are almost certain to be the same type on current systems, but documenting your intent is valuable.)

All implementations must provide `int_least64_t` and `int_fast64_t`.  It's at least theoretically possible that `int64_t` might not exist (say, if the compiler has a 128-bit type but no 64-bit type, or if signed integers aren't represented using 2's-complement).

(But in every C99-ish implementation I've ever seen, `long long` is exactly 64 bits, and `int64_t` exists.)

Answer (score -1):

Define custom type for 64-bit integer and use it in your code. Use the directive #ifdef to the compiler can choose the right one. The example for unification some integers:

```
#ifdef (_MSC_VER)

#include <basetsd.h>

#define int8_t  INT8
#define uint8_t UINT8
#define int16_t  INT16
#define uint16_t UINT16
#define int32_t INT32
#define uint32_t UINT32
#define int64_t INT64
#define uint64_t UINT64

#else

#include <inttypes.h>

#endif

typedef uint8_t u8_t;
typedef  int8_t s8_t;
typedef uint16_t u16_t;
typedef  int16_t s16_t;
typedef uint32_t u32_t;
typedef  int32_t s32_t;
typedef uint64_t u64_t;
typedef  int64_t s64_t;
```

Comment: DON'T ever put this into your headers. You're going to cause so much pain for your users

Comment: This header can cause this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614169/dealing-with-code-redefining-int-typesuint16-t-int16-t-etc-and-boost-not-lik