# -ansi -pedantic 64 bits length integers in C

Tags: c, 64-bit, int, portability

I would like to know if there is an equivalent to `int64_t` in C that would work on 32 and 64 bits platforms and that is *ansi* and *pedantic* gcc modes compliant.

I found this interesting [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160945/c-long-long-int-vs-long-int-vs-int64-t), but it relates on C++.

I tried to used `long long` but i get an `integer overflow in expression [-WOverflow]` error. Moreover `long long` is not supported by ISO C90.

I also tried what is suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373783/representing-a-64-bit-integer-in-gnu-linux), but i still have a `-WOverflow` error with using `int64_t`

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 3):

- In C89 (required by `-ansi` flag), there is no standard way to use a 64 bits integer.  You have to rely on the types provided by your implementation.
- In C99, some implementations *may* define `int64_t`, since it is an optional type. As for  `long long` (C99), there is no guarantee that its width is *exactly* of 64 bits.

Comment: I don't want to use C99. I know `long long` comes from C99 that's why i'm asking about possible equivalents in C89/C90

Comment: @ibi0tux: No, there is no standard way to do this. That's why C99 has introduced `long long` and fixed-width integers.

Comment: Do you think i can still recreate minimal fixed-length integer based on composition of fixed-length minimal structure (i.e. `char`) ?

Comment: @ibi0tux: Do you mean something like `unsigned char n[8]`? Apart from the fact it would be inefficient, it is not perfectly standard, since `CHAR_BIT` could be greater than 8. It depends on the portability you want.

Comment: Ok. I suppose making my code ANSI compliant will be more difficult that i though. Thank you.

Comment: `long long` is required to be *at least* 64 bits in width, so you might as well make use of that. By width, I don't mean `sizeof`; I mean the total number of *value* bits. Padding might influence the `sizeof` a type, without increasing the range that it can represent. Keep that in mind.